# ekko-lightbox and images returned as BLOBs from PHP scipr

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP script which returns image as BLOB content from MySQL database. So the image tag looks like

```
<img src="image.php?id=1">
```

This link returns JPEG image and it work's as such in browser. (In my PHP script I use Content-Type header, etc. and it works fine.)

ekko-lightbox does not work with such an image source since there is internal extension check! How to modify ekko-lightbox.js to accept this such a source!?

Answer (score 1):

I started to change internal ekko-lightbox JavaScript code and found out that there is the attribute `data-type="image"` that one can use to force ekko-lightbox to go into image mode (treat content as plain image). I know, I should have read docs before - RTFM.